# new anonymous struct pointer

Tags: dictionary, go, pointers, struct, new-operator

I am new to Go, and defining separate type structs is less pretty than having structs one inside other, and if i have struct like this

```
var out outter
type outter struct {
    a int
    b string
    ...
    s map[string]*struct{
        sa int
        sb string
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I could access `s` map for reading with simple `out.s["abc"].sa` ... if I could only somehow insert values to such anonymous struct. So my question is how to insert new values in map `s` somewhere in my functions.

```
out.s["abc"] = new( typeof(*out.s[""]) ) // something like that
```

Comment: You will need to repeat the type definition within the composite literals every place you need to use it, which is why defining named types is almost always easier.

Comment: @JimB can you write working example of creating new key, even if it is 'ugly' code, just to know how it looks like.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/unx3cNvpnsi. In this case the `"a"` type can be inferred, but it shows what it looks like when it can't and you need a pointer to an anonymous struct literal.

Comment: If your use case is localized to a particular scope i.e. one function - you can define a type within that scope, so it doesn't "pollute" your global scope - and you can use `make` with this scoped type.

Comment: localized-scope example: https://go.dev/play/p/85NIX0l2bmE

Answer (score 1):

With the anonymous struct the allocations are tedious but not difficult:

```
out.s = make(map[string]*struct {
    sa int
    sb string
})
out.s["abc"] = &struct {
    sa int
    sb string
}{
    sa: 1,
    sb: "hello",
}
```

(full code at https://go.dev/play/p/HVU_tQtEQ6Q).

As @JimB pointed out, this gets much easier, if you name the struct:

```
type outter struct {
    a int
    b string
    s map[string]*inner
}

type inner struct {
    sa int
    sb string
}
```

In this case you can write

```
out.s = make(map[string]*inner)
out.s["abc"] = &inner{
    sa: 1,
    sb: "hello",
}
```

(code at https://go.dev/play/p/65yWNioBSBm).